# unable to fetch facebook friend list using scrapy

Tags: python, facebook, scrapy, web-crawler, screen-scraping

## no output retrieved using any of the tags

I am trying to fetch the friendlist of a user using scrapy script i am able to get the data for the about and the other basic info sections however with the friend section the similar code does not seem to work. I am using my facebook account logged in the browser also the friendlist of the desired profile is also public. I have tried implementing the following methods:

```
In [2]: response.xpath('//div[@class="_3i9"]')
Out[2]: [<Selector xpath='//div[@class="_3i9"]' data='<div id="collection_wrapper_2327158227" '>]

In [3]: response.xpath('//div[@class="_3i9"]/div/a/@href')
Out[3]: []

In [4]: response.xpath('//div[@class="_3i9"]/div/ul/li/a/@href')
Out[4]: []

In [5]: response.xpath('//div[@class="clearfix _5qo4"]/a/@href')
Out[5]: []

In [6]: response.xpath('//div[@class="clearfix _5qo4"]')
Out[6]: []

In [7]: response.xpath('//div[@class="uiList _262m _4kg"]')
Out[7]: []

In [8]: response.xpath('//ul[@class="uiList _262m _4kg"]')
Out[8]: []

In [9]: response.xpath('//ul[@class="collection_wrapper_2356318349"]')
Out[9]: []

In [10]: response.xpath('//[@class="collection_wrapper_2356318349"]')
```

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. You have to use the API

Comment: next to what wizkid said, what´s the use case for this?

Comment: I am wondering to know if we can scrap is by simple HTML content filtering,
Use Case - Working on a minor tool for social scrapping

Answer (score -1):

In [2]: response.xpath('//div[@class="_3i9"]')
Out[2]: []

In [3]: response.xpath('//div[@class="_3i9"]/div/a/@href')
Out[3]: []

In [4]: response.xpath('//div[@class="_3i9"]/div/ul/li/a/@href')
Out[4]: []

In [5]: response.xpath('//div[@class="clearfix _5qo4"]/a/@href')
Out[5]: []

In [6]: response.xpath('//div[@class="clearfix _5qo4"]')
Out[6]: []

In [7]: response.xpath('//div[@class="uiList _262m _4kg"]')
Out[7]: []

In [8]: response.xpath('//ul[@class="uiList _262m _4kg"]')
Out[8]: []

In [9]: response.xpath('//ul[@class="collection_wrapper_2356318349"]')
Out[9]: []

In [10]: response.xpath('//[@class="collection_wrapper_2356318349"]')
share edit

Comment: Could you please explain ??